# Triangle asterisks of for loop

Tags: javascript, algorithm, for-loop

Guys I need your assistance I should accomplish several tasks given by supervisor to make triangle using for loop. But I can't get the exact one. Please help me with that!

Here is an illustration how the final output should look like:

Task 2
input
N (example: N = 5)

output

```
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```

Task 3
input
N (example: N = 5)

output

```
* * *
 * * 
* * *
 * *
* * *
```

Task 4
input
    N (example: N = 5)

output

```
*****
*   *
*   *
*   *
*****
```

and this is my code:

```
function mixedTriangle (n) {
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            document.write('*');
        }
        document.write('<br>');
    }
}
mixedTriangle(5);
```

Comment: So you have code that works for what seems to be Task 1, what have you tried for the other three tasks?

Comment: does it need to be all in one function or 3 seperate functions for each task?

Answer (score 0):

this is my take on it (scaling width with n):

first one you want to walk backwards on the columns so we start at the right side.

for the second function the we switch the pattern for each row other than that it's just using modulus to switch for each column

last one you just need the border which basically means minimum column or row or maximum column or row

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fullSign = '*';
    var emptySign = '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
    var newRowSign = '<br>';

    function mixedTriangle (n) {
        for (var row = 1; row <= n; row++) {
            for (var col = n; col > 0; col--) {
                if(col <= row)
                    document.write(fullSign);
                else
                    document.write(emptySign);
            }
            document.write('<br>');
        }
    }

    function mixedTriangle2(n) {
        for (var row = 0; row < n; row++) {
            for (var col = 0; col < n; col++) {
                if(row % 2 == 0) {
                    if(col % 2 == 0)
                        document.write(fullSign);
                    else
                        document.write(emptySign);
                }
                else {
                    if(col % 2 == 1)
                        document.write(fullSign);
                    else
                        document.write(emptySign);
                }
            }
            document.write(newRowSign);
        }
    }


    function mixedTriangle3(n) {
        for (var row = 1; row <= n; row++) {
            for (var col = 1; col <= n; col++) {
                if(row == 1 || col == 1 || col == n || row == n)
                    document.write(fullSign);
                else
                    document.write(emptySign);
            }
            document.write(newRowSign);
        }
    }


    // mixedTriangle(5);
    // mixedTriangle2(5);
    mixedTriangle3(5);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//create function
function makeDownwardStairs(height) {
  //initialize an empty array inside function.
  let pyr = [];
  //initialize loop and run a number of times
  for (let i = 1; i <= height; i++) {
    //update array w/ variable value.
    pyr += '#'
    //Prints the array to the console
    console.log(pyr)
  }
}
// calls the function
makeDownwardStairs(5);
```